# Math interval notations: Interval raised to a power?

Tags: notation

I saw this equation in a paper:

$v = (v_{l,0}, v_{r,0}, v_{l,1}, v_{r,1}, v_{l,2}, v_{r,2}, v_{l,3}, v_{r,3}) ∈ [−1, 1]^8 $

What does this interval notation mean?- $[−1, 1]^8$

Comment: It means $8$ copies of the interval $[-1,1]$.

Comment: As @Idonknow said it is $[-1,1]^8=\underbrace{[-1,1]\times\cdots\times[-1,1]}_{8 \text{ times}}$

Comment: @Idonknow  Did you mean $[-1, 1]$?

Comment: This fit with the fact that $v$ is an $8$-uple.

Comment: Consider the simpler case: $(0,\dfrac 1 2) \in [-1,1] \times [-1,1]$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: Where $(0, \frac12)$ does *not* mean an open interval. :-)

Answer (score 3):

It is exponentiation in the context of the Cartesian product of sets. For example:
\begin{align}
[-1, 1]^3 
&= [-1, 1] \times [-1, 1] \times [-1, 1] \\
&= \{ (x_1, x_2, x_3) \mid x_1, x_2, x_3 \in [-1, 1] \}
\end{align}

Comment: I saw that exponentiation of an integral can mean something else in [interval arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_arithmetic#Elementary_functions), is this correct?  How would you distinguish between the Cartesian product and this alternative?

Comment: The above Cartesian triple product describes a set in three dimensions, a cube. The interval arithmetic variant would yield another interval, thus a set in one dimension. So it is different in general. About the notation I can only guess. Probably the shorter notation is used for the interval arithmetic multiplication and power and the Cartesian product would use a longer but different notation, e.g. $\times_{k=1}^3 [-1, 1]$. Or a funny accent. Or whatever. I would need to go look in interval arithmetic literature to find out what is used there.

Answer (score 1):

$$[-1,1]^8=\left\{ (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h) : a\in[-1,1] \text{ and }b\in[-1,1]\text{ and } \cdots \text{ and } h\in[-1,1]\right\}$$

It’s the interval version of the [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product).

Formally, one should use $\wedge$ instead of “$\text{ and }$.”

Answer (score 0):

***[-1, 1]*** represents a subspace of 1-Dimensional space ( R ) where x<sub>1</sub> is constrained to lie in [-1, 1].

**Similarly, [-1, 1]^<sup>8</sup> represents subspace of 8-Dimensional space ( R^<sup>8</sup> ), where each of the x<sub>i</sub>'s is bound to lie in [-1, 1].**

> *In other words, a 8-tuple ( x<sub>1</sub>, x<sub>2</sub>, ... x<sub>8</sub> ) will lie in [-1, 1]^<sup>8</sup> if each of the x<sub>i</sub>'s lies in [-1, 1].*

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers are wrong.  Let w be the interval [-2,3].
Then the meaning of w^2 is this:  Let L= the minimum value of
x^2 for x in w. let H = the maximum value of x^2 for x in w.
Then the interval result for w^2 is {L,H].
In this case the smallest value is 0, the largest is 9, so the answer is [0,9].
By contrast,   [-2,3] ^2 is the interval [-6,9].
RJF

Comment: No, it's just the Cartesian product of sets. $[a,b] \times [a,b] = [a,b]^2$ which is also known as $\left\{(x,y) : x,y \in [a,b]\right\}$

Comment: Much as I hate to credit Wolfram's Mathematica,  let v=Interval[{-2,3}]   and u= Interval[{-2,3}].  v^2 computes as Interval[{0,9}].  u*v computes as Interval[{-6,9}].   I just noticed that stackexchange mangled my previous note.. That last line should be ... By contrast [-2,3] times [-2,3]  is ....    Anyway, you (and others) can define "arithmetic intervals" as ranges, but why not distinguish them?  See IEEE std 1788-2015 on the subject.

Comment: I have no idea how Mathematica does it. I don't know what you mean by distinguishing arithmetic intervals.

Comment: IEEE 1788 page 28 table 9.1 refers to pown  [power of interval to an integer] as mapping x^p  for interval x and p an even integer, to the range [0, infinity)

Comment: One can distinguish a segment of the real line  (call it a range, or a set) from an arithmetic point "interval".  The latter is a concept such that x in [a,b]  means that x is a particular real number, such that  a<=x<=b   [unless a,b, infinity in which case inequal]. It does not mean the set of real numbers from a to b.  You can choose to view intervals as ranges or sets, and compute unions and intersections etc. It's just not the same concept as the point function. Which is apparently Mathematica's take on it, at least for this example.

Comment: Looking at the original question ...  rather than the title ...  the most likely meaning is that for each element  -1 <= v_{a,b} <=1.  Which is not a power of an interval.

Comment: Well, I guess you're right if we are using the interval arithmetic variant, which would yield another interval, thus a set in one dimension.